# Не срабатывает вызов каждые 1000 миллисекунд

Tags: javascript

Автор утверждает, что тут каждый 1000 миллисекунд можно вызывать эту функцию.

Пятый вызов просто не работает.

```js
let f = debounce(alert, 1000);
function debounce(f, ms) {

  let isCooldown = false;

  return function() {
    if (isCooldown) return;

    f.apply(this, arguments);

    isCooldown = true;

    setTimeout(() => isCooldown = false, ms);
  };

}
f(1); // runs immediately
f(2); // ignored

setTimeout( () => f(3), 100); // ignored ( only 100 ms passed )
setTimeout( () => f(4), 1100); // runs
setTimeout( () => f(5), 2150);
```

Почему мне дебагер тут никак не помогает?

Comment: и я думаю дебаггер бы помог если опять же не использовтать `alert`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сделайте не `alert` а например `console.log()` и все отработает, Вы не успеваете закрыть `alert` за секунду..

```js
let f = debounce(i=>console.log(i), 1000);
function debounce(f, ms) {

  let isCooldown = false;

  return function() {
    if (isCooldown) return;

    f.apply(this, arguments);

    isCooldown = true;

    setTimeout(() => isCooldown = false, ms);
  };

}
f(1); // runs immediately
f(2); // ignored

setTimeout( () => f(3), 100); // ignored ( only 100 ms passed )
setTimeout( () => f(4), 1100); // runs
setTimeout( () => f(5), 2150);
```

А лучше повесьте функцию на кнопку

```js
let f = debounce(e => console.log(e.textContent), 1000);

function debounce(f, ms) {
  let isCooldown = false;
  return function() {
    if (isCooldown) return;
    f.apply(this, arguments);
    isCooldown = true;
    setTimeout(e => isCooldown = false, ms);
  };
}
```

```html
<button onclick="f(this)">1</button>
<button onclick="f(this)">2</button>
<button onclick="f(this)">3</button>
```

---

Вот Вам версия от меня, без таймаутов =)

```js
let f = debounce(e => console.log(e.textContent), 1000);

function debounce(f, ms) {
  let last = 0;
  return function() {
    let t = Date.now()
    if (last + ms > t) 
      return;
    f.apply(this, arguments, last = t);
  };
}
```

```html
<button onclick="f(this)">1</button>
<button onclick="f(this)">2</button>
<button onclick="f(this)">3</button>
```

Comment: А как этот код работает, я как ни чекаю его через дебаг - никак не пойму, особенно - почему когда  isCooldown = false; оно работает, а если true - net, да, там ретурн останавливает выполнение функции, но вот этот код вообще не понятен, как и многое в jse)

 f.apply(this, arguments);

    isCooldown = true;

    setTimeout(() => isCooldown = false, ms);

Comment: `особенно - почему когда isCooldown = false; оно работает, а если true - net` ну так условие `if (isCooldown) return;` сделает выход их функции если `cooldown=true`, вроде все так и есть

Comment: Мне именно код не понятен, почему когда мы используем     setTimeout(() => isCooldown = false, ms);
оно призывает этот f, какое оно к нему имеет отношение? Всё как-то запутанно, я мб просто не внимательный(

Comment: код вызывает  `f.apply(this, arguments);`  а  `setTimeout(() => isCooldown = false, 1000)` выполнит `isCooldown = false` через 1000 мс, т.е. разрешит дальнейшие вызовы