# Отмена click на 5 секунд

Tags: javascript

Ломаю себе голову уже второй час. Может кто поможет:

```js
$('#mybtn').click(function() {
  myfunc();
});

function myfunc() {

  console.log('запустили функцию')

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="mybtn" class=""><h1>кнопка</h1></button>
```

Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы console.log запускался при условии,
 что прошло не меньше 5 секунд с первого запуска функции.
Хочу это сделать внутри myfunc()

Тоесть человек кликает на кнопку #mybtn, функция выполняется, дальше если человек еще 10 раз кликает на кнопку на протяжении 5 секунд то ничего не срабатывает. Функция начинает работать опять через 5 секунд, и с таким интервалом.

Помогите, а)

Comment: "Ломаю себе голову уже второй час" - кошмар и ужас. аж целых два часа! А люди раньше днями сидели, чтобы подольше посидеть подумать и решить всё же задачу и насладиться результатом

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/999963/188366

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Все что нужно это, это отключит кнопку, зачем ее кликать.

```
 this.disabled = true;
  setInterval(() => {
    this.disabled = false;
  }, 5000);
```

```js
$('#mybtn').click(function() {
  myfunc();
  this.disabled = true;
  setInterval(() => {
    this.disabled = false;
  }, 5000);
});

function myfunc() {

  console.log('запустили функцию')

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="mybtn" class=""><h1>кнопка</h1></button>
```

Answer (score 4):

```js
mybtn_enabled = true;
$('#mybtn').click(function() {
    myfunc();
});

function myfunc(){
  if (mybtn_enabled) {
    mybtn_enabled = false;
    setTimeout(function(){
      mybtn_enabled = true;
    }, 5000);
    console.log('запустили функцию');
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="mybtn" class=""><h1>кнопка</h1></button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Пока флаг свободен - производим действия, ставим флаг, по таймеру освобождаем флаг. Если флаг занят - ничего не делаем.

```
    var flag = true;
    function myfunc(){
      if(flag) { 
        console.log('запустили функцию');
        flag = false;
        setTimeout(function() {
          flag = true; 
        }, 5000);
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Добавьте в список переменных значение time и используйте таймер

Я могу ошибаться, но вроде, это будет работать:

```js
var time = true;

$('#mybtn').click(function() {
    if (time = true) myfunc();
});

function myfunc(){
 
  console.log('запустили функцию')
  time = false;
  setTimeout(function(){time = true;}, 5000);

}
```